# C++ vector issue - 'LNK2001: unresolved external symbol private: static...'

Tags: c++

Before anyone calls me out for not looking at pre-existing questions, I have looked and realise that it is to do with declaration, but I still can't get it to work (might be something to do with me using vectors).

Manager.h:

```
#include "Flight.h"
#ifndef manager_h
#define manager_h

class Manager {
    static vector<Airport> airports;
    static vector<Flight> flights;
public:
    static void loadAirports();
    static void loadFlights();
    static Airport getAirport(string code);
    static vector<string> split(const string &s, vector<string> &elems);
};

#endif
```

Manager.cpp:

```
#include "Manager.h"

void Manager::loadAirports ()
{
    ifstream airportfile("airports.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(airportfile, line))
    {
        vector<string> values;
        split(line, values);
        Airport airport (values[0], values[1], atoi(values[2].c_str()));
        airports.push_back(airport);
    }
}

void Manager::loadFlights ()
{
    ifstream flightfile("flights.txt");
    string line;
    while (getline(flightfile, line))
    {
        vector<string> values;
        split(line, values);
        Flight flight (getAirport(values[0]), getAirport(values[1]), atoi(values[2].c_str()), atoi(values[3].c_str()));
        flights.push_back(flight);
    }
    cout << flights.size() << endl;
}

Airport Manager::getAirport (string code)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < (int)airports.size(); i++)
    {
        if (airports[i].code == code)
            return airports[i];
    }
    throw exception();
}

vector<string> Manager::split(const string &s, vector<string> &elems) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    string item;
    while(getline(ss, item, ',')) {
        elems.push_back(item);
    }
    return elems;
}
```

It is throwing this error:

> Manager.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static struct Vector
>   Manager::airports"
>   (?airports@Manager@@0U?$Vector@UAirport@@@@A)
>
> Manager.obj : error LNK2001:
>   unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static struct Vector
>   Manager::flights"
>   (?flights@Manager@@0U?$Vector@UFlight@@@@A)

I realise i need to define the vectors, but how and where? I tried creating an empty constructor and then doing

```
Manager::Manager ()
{
    vector<string> flights;
    vector<string> airports;
}
```

But it just gave me a re-definition error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to define them in the `.cpp` file:

```
vector<string> Manager::flights;
vector<string> Manager::airports;
```

Comment: why are they <string> and not <Airports>?

Answer (score 25):

In your .cpp file, you need to add the *definitions* of the static variables:

```
vector<Airport> Manager::airports;
vector<Flight> Manager::flights;
```

See [*Why are classes with static data members getting linker errors?*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12) from the C++ FAQ.

Comment: Oh i didn't realise it had to go outside any kind of function or constructor.

Comment: There is only one instance of a static so no constructor would be appropriate. It's a lot like the way you declare/define global variables. E.g. in header: `extern int count;` and in source file: `int count = 0;`. (Also note that `static` has various different meanings depending on where you find it.)

Answer (score 5):

Oli and Constantinius have answered your actual question, but I would recommend changing the class. As it stands it has only static members, so you can never create an object of this class. While this is legal C++, it is not in the spirit of C++ (Although there are other languages that do embrace this usage, such as C#)

All static members imply that you are trying for some kind of singleton, but there are more standard ways of enforcing the singleton-ness of a class.

Having said that - I advocate *never* building singleton-ness *into* a class. Rather write the class as a normal class, and provide a singleton wrapper. This also has the neat side effect of preventing the notorious *static initialization order fiasco* that your current code is liable to bump into.

So, something like (excluding the includes for brevity):

Manager.h

```
class Manager {
    vector<Airport> airports;
    vector<Flight> flights;
public:
    Manager();
    void loadAirports();
    void loadFlights();
    Airport getAirport(string code);
    vector<string> split(const string &s, vector<string> &elems);
};

Manager& GetManager();
```

Manager.cpp

```
Manager::Manager()
{
    loadAirports();
    loadFlights();
}

Manager& GetManager()
{
    static Manager manager;
    return manager;
}
```

Comment: Oh - and a seperate sidenote - if you use `std::set<Airport>` or `std::map<Airport>` instead of `std::vector<Airport>`, you can avoid the linear search in `getAirport`.